# Remote access to webserver in docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu-server

I've started using docker for dev, with the following setup:

- Host machine - ubuntu server.
- Docker container - webapp w/ tomcat server (using https).

As far as host-container access goes - everything works fine. 
**However**, I can't manage to access the container's webapp from a remote machine (though still within the same network).

When running

```
docker port <container-id> 443
```

output is as expected, so docker's port binding seems fine.

```
172.16.*.*:<random-port>
```

**Any ideas?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured out what I missed, so here's a simple flow for accessing docker containers webapps from remote machines:

**Step #1** : Bind physical host ports (e.g. 22, 443, 80, ...) to container's virtual ports.
possible syntax:

```
    docker run -p 127.0.0.1:443:3444 -d <docker-image-name>
```

(see [docker docs for port redirection](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/port_redirection/) with all options)

**Step #2** : Redirect host's physical port to container's allocated virtual port. possible (linux) syntax:

```
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i <host-interface-device> -p tcp --dport <host-physical-port> -j REDIRECT --to-port <container-virtual-port>
```

That should cover the basic use case.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Correct me if I'm wrong but as far as I'm aware docker host creates a private network for it's containers which is inaccessible from the outside. That said your best bet would probably be to access the container at {host_IP}:{mapped_port}.

Comment: You're right, and should work this way (see [docker.io : port redirection](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/port_redirection/)). However, my problem seems to be related to my host (ubuntu server 13.10), which doesn't redirect me to the container when accessing https://{host_IP}:{mapped_port} from a remote machine.

Answer (score 2):

If your container was built with a Dockerfile that has an `EXPOSE` statement, e.g. `EXPOSE 443`, then you can start the container with the `-P` option (as in "publish" or "public"). The port will be made available to connections from remote machines:

```
$ docker run -d -P mywebservice
```

If you didn't use a Dockerfile, or if it didn't have an `EXPOSE` statement (it should!), then you can also do an explicit port mapping:

```
$ docker run -d -p 80 mywebservice
```

In both cases, the result will be a publicly-accessible port:

```
$ docker ps
9bcb… mywebservice:latest … 0.0.0.0:49153->80/tcp …
```

Last but not least, you can force the port number if you need to:

```
$ docker run -d -p 8442:80 mywebservice
```

In that case, connecting to your Docker host IP address on port 8442 will reach the container.

Answer (score 0):

There are some alternatives of how to access docker containers from an external device (in the same network), check out this post for more information http://blog.nunes.io/2015/05/02/how-to-access-docker-containers-from-external-devices.html