# Mac: how to remotely access server running inside docker container from other computers?

Tags: macos, networking, docker, boot2docker

First I installed boot2docker on OSX 10.10, then I successfully ran a web container. With [port redirection configuration](https://fogstack.wordpress.com/2014/02/09/docker-on-osx-port-forwarding/), I can browse the web server by `localhost:8080` in the browser. Now I want to access the server from other computers, in the same WLAN, by using of url `my-mac-ip:8080`. I googled over and tried many ways, still not figured out the solution.

I found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21970337/remote-access-to-webserver-in-docker-container), but iptables doesn't work for OSX.

I'm new to Docker and I'm not familiar with network configuration, please help me out! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like it isn't a Docker problem because you can access localhost:8080. I think you need to open port 8080 on your laptop to make it possible for others to access it from outside.

To open a port under Max OS X 10.10 foolowd [this guide](http://salferrarello.com/mac-pfctl-port-forwarding), it describes how to usw pfctl for port forwarding.

Comment: Agreed, I just didn't know how to open port for my Mac. For the above link, 10.10 has changed a lot, I failed to set up...

Comment: Maybe these two links are helpful [first](http://salferrarello.com/mac-pfctl-port-forwarding/) and [second](http://www.abetobing.com/blog/port-forwarding-mac-os-yosemite-81.html)

Comment: awesome, the first working! please update your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can setup temporary port forwarding as follows:

On your Mac:

```
$ ifconfig | grep 192
    inet 192.168.1.21 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet 192.168.59.3 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.59.255

$ docker run -d -P --name web nginx
$ docker port web
  443/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:49153
  80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:49154
$ boot2docker ssh -vnNTL 192.168.1.21:8080:localhost:49154
```

On a PC or any other device on the same 192.168.1 LAN, you can now access the nginx server with http://192.168.1.21:8080

See also [boot2docker workarounds](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/WORKAROUNDS.md#port-forwarding-on-steroids).