# Remote access to container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, iptables, jupyter-notebook

I have a remote server - outside LAN, with public IP. I would like to create a simple start script which runs my container and shares its port to the outside world.

I have the following script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# 8088 should be open host port
docker run -d -v /home/user/nb/:/root -p 8889:8088 kaggle/python jupyter-notebook --no-browser --port=8889

sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i em1 -p tcp --dport 8088 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8088
```

But, after executing the script, I do not have open port 8088 on the server.

```
tcp        0      0 10.0.3.1:53             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          17333       -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          13560       -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       9643        -                            
tcp6       0      0 fa81::3a6e:7afe:fe6b:52 :::*                    LISTEN      114        17345       -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          13562       -               
tcp6       0      0 :::8889                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          17509       -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    LISTEN      1000       9642        -
```

So I can not connect using a browser from other hosts, like this:

```
[IPv4_OF_SERVER]:8088
```

The server runs Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

The script was based on
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22050818/902691

But I also tried another solution - port are closed on server after run.

**EDIT:**
After changes of port according to @Felix:

```
$ netstat -anlet
tcp        0      0 10.0.3.1:53             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          15758      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          15404      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       14823         
tcp6       0      0 fa81::3a6e:7afe:fe6b:52 :::*                    LISTEN      114        13312      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          15406      
tcp6       0      0 :::8088                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          9985       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    LISTEN      1000       14822     

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                 COMMAND               CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                   NAMES
8c83ab3fb45c  kaggle/python:latest  "/usr/bin/tini -- ju  42 seconds ago  Up 41 seconds  0.0.0.0:8088->8088/tcp  angry_thompson
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined the port `8889` to be reachable by your public domain with this part:
`-p 8889:8088`

If you want to be able to access the container by the port 8088 than change your starting command to : `-p 8088:8088`

[edit]
As I saw, than your IPv6 Address is bind to that port. To be sure that the IPv4 is working as well, you can use 
`-p IP:8088:8088` OR `-p 0.0.0.0:8088:8088`

Comment: I changed It but netstat still do not see LISTEN 8088 port.

Comment: could you post the result of `docker ps` and the new netstat result?

Comment: Command `docker ps` 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
8c83ab3fb45c        kaggle/python:latest   "/usr/bin/tini -- ju   42 seconds ago      Up 41 seconds       0.0.0.0:8088->8088/tcp   angry_thompson

Rest is too long for comment I add it in post as EDIT.